# insert checkbox array to database

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, checkbox

i have multiple checkboxes that i want to insert to my database.

i have this code where im trying to take all the checkbox values via array, but what im inserting on the database are blank, perhaps im taking the array the wrong way

checkboxes

```
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="modalday" name="modalday[]" value="M">Monday
&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
   <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="modalday" name="modalday[]" value="T">Tuesday
   &nbsp;&nbsp;</label> 
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
   <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="modalday" name="modalday[]" value="W">Wednesday
   &nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
   <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="modalday" name="modalday[]" value="Th">Thursday
   &nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="modalday" name="modalday[]" value="F">Friday
&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
```

this is how i take the data

```
 function saveData(){
                      var modsubj = $('#modalsubject').val();
                      var modsect = $('#modalsection').val();
                      var modstart = $('#modalstarttime').val();
                      var modend = $('#modalendtime').val();
                      var moduser = $('#userID').val();
                      var modday = new Array();

                      $('.modalday input:checked').each(function() {
                        modday.push($(this).attr('name'));
                      });

                      $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "modal.funcs.php?p=add",
                        data: "subj="+modsubj+"&sect="+modsect+"&day="+modday+"&start="+modstart+"&end="+modend+"&user="+moduser
                      });

                    }
```

and this is where i process the data taken from ajax

```
$page = isset($_GET['p'])?$_GET['p']:'';
if($page=='add'){

  $subj = $_POST['subj'];
  $sect = $_POST['sect']; 
  $day = $_POST['day'];
  $strTime = $_POST['start'];
  $endTime = $_POST['end'];
  $user_id = $_POST['user'];



  $auth_user->createSchedule($subj,$sect,$day,$strTime,$endTime,$user_id);
  $schedRow = $auth_user->readSchedule();

} else if ($page=='edit') {

}
```

i think whats wrong is how i take the data from the array, but im not sure how to do it correctly, please help

Comment: `modday.push($(this).attr('name'));` - You are pushing the name which will be just `modalday` for every item, you need to push the value instead

Comment: what value? is modalday the correct parameter for this?

Comment: `$(this).val()` should probably do it - http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: i think this is right, i did it but its still not inserting any value, perhaps im getting something wrong in the inserting part? where i take the post values?

Comment: [`$(form).serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) does all that conversion for you.

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: yes i did all of that @JayBlanchard

Comment: what do you get when you do a var_dump of the $day variable and what type is the createSchedule function expecting? Unfortunately, we just don't have enough information as is...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is where your code is wrong:

```
$('.modalday input:checked').each(function() {
   modday.push($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

You should get the value of the checkbox, not the name of the element it. So do this:

```
$('.modalday input:checked').each(function() {
   modday.push($(this).val());
});
```

or even just change the 'name' to 'value':

```
$('.modalday input:checked').each(function() {
    modday.push($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Then, in order to send the data to PHP post,
the string should be look like this:

```
modalday[]=T&modalday[]=W&modalday[]=Th
```

So either you use looping to create the strings, or just use $(form).serialize(), like this:

wrap your check box in form:

```
<form id="checkboxform">
<!-- your check box codes here -->
</form>
```

The you jquery code:

```
var params = $('#checkboxform').serialize();

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "modal.funcs.php?p=add",
   data: params,
});
```

See my Js Fiddle example code: https://jsfiddle.net/0y84tws2/

Comment: i did this but its still not inserting anything, i think i still have something wrong somewhere besides this

Comment: before do the ajax call from PHP, try console.log() your checkbox array variable. and see in the console if there is any error

Comment: try changing the ```day``` in the ajax "data" to ```day[]```

Comment: it inserted a text "Array", why is that

Comment: I have included a jsfiddle example link @KentAbrio

Comment: do i still need the modday array? or the params value is enough?

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention, just put all other input field inside the same form, then when you use the ```serialize()``` function, it will automatically convert all your input to the string. So then just ```params``` value is enough.

Comment: then how will i insert params as individual columns in my database?

Comment: just use the PHP to fetch the $_POST value like usual, but change the ```$day = $_POST['day'];``` to ```$day = $_POST['modalday'];```. now the ```$day``` variable is an array. Then just loop through the array and store into your table.

Comment: thank you so much sir for your time, i really appreciate this. i know your code works fine, im just inexperience with ajax that i cant implement it properly,

Comment: You're welcome. One more thing you could just use ```explode(',',$day)``` to convert the ```$day``` array into strings seperated by coma, and store in your table column.

Answer (score 0):

i found a simpler way to do this,

in my jquery, i change my previous code to this

```
var modday = [];

                        $('.modalday').each(function() {
                          if($(this).is(":checked")){
                            modday.push($(this).val());
                          }
                        });

                        modday = modday.toString();

                        $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: "modal.funcs.php?p=add",
                          data: "subj="+modsubj+"&sect="+modsect+"&day="+modday+"&start="+modstart+"&end="+modend+"&user="+moduser
                        });
```

and in my php, this is how i took the values, fairly simple

```
$page = isset($_GET['p'])?$_GET['p']:'';
if($page=='add'){

    if(isset($_POST['day'])){
        $subj = $_POST['subj'];
        $sect = $_POST['sect']; 
        $day = $_POST['day'];
        $strTime = $_POST['start'];
        $endTime = $_POST['end'];
        $user_id = $_POST['user'];

        $auth_user->createSchedule($subj,$sect,$day,$strTime,$endTime,$user_id);
        $schedRow = $auth_user->readSchedule();
    }
```